# Generate random int in 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

l would like to generate a random 3d array containing random  integers (coordinates)  in the intervalle [0,100].

so, `coordinates=dim(30,10,2)`

What l have tried ?

```
coordinates = [[random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)] for _i in range(30)]
```

which returns

```
array([[97, 68],
       [11, 23],
       [47, 99],
       [52, 58],
       [95, 60],
       [89, 29],
       [71, 47],
       [80, 52],
       [ 7, 83],
       [30, 87],
       [53, 96],
       [70, 33],
       [36, 12],
       [15, 52],
       [30, 76],
       [61, 52],
       [87, 99],
       [19, 74],
       [37, 63],
       [40,  2],
       [ 8, 84],
       [70, 32],
       [63,  8],
       [98, 89],
       [27, 12],
       [75, 59],
       [76, 17],
       [27, 12],
       [48, 61],
       [39, 98]])
```

of shape `(30,10)`

What l'm supposed to get ?

dim=(30,10,2) rather than (30,10)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [`size` parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
import numpy as np
coordinates = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(30, 10, 2))
```

will produce a NumPy array with integer values between 0 and 100 and of shape `(30, 10, 2)`.